# Find real link form redirect 301,302

Tags: php, curl, header

I see some service sort link(tinyurl,goo.gl,bit.ly ...)
I use  php function get_headers do get header and find real link from sort links
this is mycode

```
function get_furl($url)
{
    $furl = false;

    // First check response headers
    $headers = get_headers($url);

    // Test for 301 or 302
    if(preg_match('/^HTTP\/\d\.\d\s+(301|302)/',$headers[0]))
    {
        foreach($headers as $value)
        {
            if(substr(strtolower($value), 0, 9) == "location:")
            {
                $furl = trim(substr($value, 9, strlen($value)));
            }
        }
    }
    // Set final URL
    $furl = ($furl) ? $furl : $url;

    return $furl;
}
```

But some time ,Script was  got header time out.Help me code get real link faster.
Geat thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it any faster. Timeouts happen sometimes, and you need to take care of that.

By the way, the `strlen()` is unnecessary.